# Traceback error with Number-Plate-Search issue, not able to run program

Tags: python, selenium, traceback

I'm trying to run python bot.py from Number-Plate-Search on github but keep getting traceback error:

Link: https://github.com/sinarest1608/Number-plate-search

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 1, in 
from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium

Comment: You don't have the `selenium` module installed.

Comment: Make sure to install [the requirements](https://github.com/sinarest1608/Number-plate-search/blob/master/requirements.txt), e.g. by running `pip install -r requirements.txt` in a virtual environment.